# How to create video thumbnail from video path?

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails

My code of generating video thumbnail from video path but getting null

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: this method is deprecated, use new one instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils#createAudioThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: do you have implementation of the new method, thanks.